# Angular ng-repeat multiple row table with select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this table with select boxes on each row. The problem is that when I make a change in one select box, all of them get changed showing the same value. What I need is to unbind all select boxes to be able to have different selections on each one of them.

Code goes like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in userMappings.items" ng-model="item.mapped">
  <td class="col-md-3" ng-model="mappingType.name">
    {{item.idsport}}, Game Type {{item.idgametype}}, {{item.name}} (Current limit {{item.value}})
  </td>                   
   <td class="col-md-3 mapType" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 15px" >
    <h4>Mapping Type: <span style="font-size:0.8em">{{selectedType}}</span> </h4> <br />
    <select ng-model="mappingType.name" ng-change="which($index); selectedRow()" ng-options="item.name for item in mappingType"></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not really clear how your data is structured here and that's really important information to answer this question.

Comment: $scope.mappingType = [{name: "Sport"}, {name: "League"}, {name: "No Mapping"}];

Then I have a table of about 1000 objects. If I make a selection on one select, all the other get updated showing the same value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ng-model` to bind to `mappingTypes.name` it will modify the property on the controller scope because that's where it's defined. `mappingTypes` isn't part of `ng-repeat`'s scope so it goes through the scope inheritance chain and updates it there. So when you select an item, `mappingTypes` is now an array with a `name` property. All of your items bind to that same array, so they all have the same value.

If you want to only change a specific item in `ng-repeat`, you should use something like `item.mapping`. if you modify anything other than `item` it's modifying the entire controller's scope.

Comment: Hi Scott, where exactly do I have to use  item.mapping?

Comment: For your `<select>` you can use `ng-model="item.mapping"`, which means that when you select something from the dropdown it now gets set on the item rather than the controller scope.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. But now I would like to know, how to retrieve the "name" attribute on the selected option without using ng-model?